# Simplest way for animation?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, keyframes, parent

I trying to animate this scene using keyframes for rotation and location, but looks like this is not the way ... first and last frames are OK, but in between parts are disconnected ...

**What is simplest way to get parts animated but connected?**

[image]

Regards

Comment: We can't do much without the .blend file. Please provide it so we can understand the context of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: besides of KISKAarts comment, which i agree, i would also describe how the animation should look like and even better add a link with an animation, how it should look like, so that we don't have to guess or ask how it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a two bone armature for turning the wheel.  The parent boned will be a child in the axle assembly, parented to the axle.  The child bone 'Bone.001' will be in charge of the wheel's rotation animation.

Here we wee a 2-bone armature responsible for the axle movement (Bone) and Cylinder rotation (Bone.001).   I first create armature and cylinder aligned to each other,

[image]

make sure the parent bone's movement or rotation will not affect the cylinder (turn off "Deform" for the parent "Bone").
[image]

I then Parent with Auto Weight: Cylinder to Armature:

[image]

Here is the animation object hierarchy,  The axle will move and rotation, as will the Bone.001 when the wheel should move.

[image]

For the *simplified* wheel rotation, I made it (Bone.001) continuous, although you'd want it to start/stop/accelerate/decelerate (another topic).  In this case I animated the Y-axis points around 0 and 60 for 60degree rotation, and set Extrapolation mode to Linear (no acceleration/deceleration), adding a Cycles modifier with "Repeat with Offset" settings.  I could set up several copies of these with "Restrict Frame range" (for example, waiting at a stop-light).

[image]
[image]

This is for a *simplified* wheel animation.  If you actually want the wheel rotation to authentically synchronize with the frame movement, In my case I've used drivers that might be based on the overall vehicle movement; can get rather complex when the vehicle makes turns, etc.

Here is my example: [image]

Comment: Hello James_T, thanks so much for your reply. I do not need wheel to rotate. Attached file crashes my Blender 3.2.2 but I'll try to follow your steps.

Comment: If Blender 3.2 crashes it's probably because of the new Blender 3.6+ file format. The format has been changed. Blender 3.6 can read both formats (old and new).